# Проблема в коде или же в самой среде?

Tags: python

Решаю задачу 27 из ЕГЭ по информатике и не могу понять: почему при решении [задачи](https://inf-ege.sdamgia.ru/test?id=9078823&nt=True&pub=False) перебором цикл, доходя до миллиона, топчется на месте и дальше ничего не вычисляет. Понимаю, что можно привести более экономное по затратам решение, но всё-таки в чем проблема? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
file = open("27988_B.txt")
n = int(file.readline())

mas = []

for i in range(n):
    mas.append(int(file.readline()))

max_R = 0

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1, n):
        R = mas[i] * mas[j]
        if R % 26 == 0:
            max_R = R
            print(R)
print(max_R)
```

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста ваш код в текстовом виде.

Comment: почему думаешь, что топчется и не вычисляет? Ничего не выводит не означает. что ничего не делает.

Comment: `доходя до миллиона` -  по условию произведение не может быть более миллиона. Что означает "топчется на месте"?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что из файла `27988_B.txt` на вход программе подаётся 60000 чисел, проход по вложенным циклам 60000*60000 раз делается очень долго (в Google Colab по моим прикидкам ожидалось где-то минут 15 до конца перебора). Но если посмотреть в файл, то можно увидеть, что одни и те же числа там много раз повторяются, что не удивительно - ведь по условиям задачи числа не могут быть больше 1000, т.е. в списке может быть всего 1000 уникальных чисел, а фактически их ещё меньше. Так что можно сильно сократить время проверки, если оставить для перебора только уникальные числа (можно и сразу собирать числа в множество, но я привожу вариант для простого исправления кода):

```
mas = list(set(mas))
n = len(mas)
```

Кстати, у вас в коде вообще нет проверки, что полученное число максимальное из возможных, код нужно поправить (а вот на скриншоте такая проверка есть).

Answer (score 1):

Приведённый код квадратичный, и не подходит для решения при указанных ограничениях (100000 элементов).

Линейный код может выглядеть примерно так. Ищутся максимумы среди чисел, кратных 26 (и следующее по рангу), чётных но не кратных 13, кратных 13 нечётных, и всех остальных.

```
#mas = [52, 12, 39, 55, 23]
#mas = [53, 12, 39, 55, 23]
#mas = [51, 13, 39, 55, 23]
mas = [52, 12, 39, 51, 23, 78]


max26 = 0
max26_2 = 0
max2 = 0
max13 = 0
maxother = 0

for x in mas:
    if x % 26 == 0:
        if x >= max26:
            max26_2 = max26
            max26 = x
    elif x % 2 == 0:
        max2 = max(max2, x)
    elif x % 13 == 0:
        max13 = max(max13, x)
    else:
        maxother = max(maxother, x)

if max26:
    print(max26 * max(max2, max13, maxother, max26_2))
else:
    print(max2 * max13)
```

Comment: Чисел то может быть 100000, но при этом каждое из них не больше 1000, т.е. фактически во всём списке не больше 1000 разных чисел, а 1000*1000 уже вполне приемлемый перебор. Хотя, конечно, аналитическое упрощение вычислений - это всегда отлично. )

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, это Вы хорошо подметили. С сетом только напрямую не пойдёт по причине, из-за которой я второе кратное 26 добавил - нужно такие числа особо обрабатывать (пример - когда два числа по 78 дают максимум)